# How do I add a js/jquery animation to pull down a div on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, web, jquery-animate

Observe [before hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxAYS.jpg) and [after hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVlhy.png). Instead of instantly switching, I want to create the effect that the header is being pulled down and expanded. So basically, I want the new div to appear from the top down. The html structure is as follows:

```html
<a href="#" id='featured-article'>
 <img src="img/iraq-war.jpg" class='fluid'>
 <h1 class='center-text'>Featured Article: The War In Iraq</h1>
 <div class="mouse-over">
      <p>The Iraq War was controversial at the time blah blah blah</p>
 </div>
</a>
```

Is there a handy way to do this with jquery? Perhaps a library or something? Or worst comes to worst, I'd like to see the raw js. Or other suggestions. Thanks

Comment: It's possible to do this with [pure CSS animations](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/). Use `:hover` to trigger the animation on mouseover.

Comment: @Evan, did you see my answer? If it works, please accept it as a courtesy.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `slideDown()`:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".center-text").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).next().stop().slideDown();
  }).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).next().stop().slideUp();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id='featured-article'>
  <img src="http://panzura.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/google-logo.png" class='fluid' />
  <h1 class='center-text'>Featured Article: Article</h1>
  <div class="mouse-over">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi amet accusamus saepe, velit recusandae minus deserunt natus architecto quos ex. Error, labore, sed. Unde, velit, labore. Quam qui commodi accusamus.</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Why have you used `.stop()`?